# Does any site track the mass of the ISS?

Tags: iss

Watching the daily ISS live broadcast from NASA the PRO mentioned the specific mass of the ISS complex (today) and what it would be when the Soyuz leaves shortly.

One can find out the mass of each upward flight, but the mass of the departing trash-loaded craft is sometimes not so clear. Its obviously important for repositioning burns to know the mass of ISS any time. Is this made available on a continuous basis (via NASA, ESA, Roscosmos etc)?

I can find Mass estimates, such as [here](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/main/onthestation/facts_and_figures.html): 419,455 kilograms, but I can't find recent information.

I'm wondering, if the mass was plotted graphically (over time) what would it be like? Does more stuff go up than down, for example?

Comment: This may be relevant: http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/logistics-reduction-and-repurposing-project

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Space Station live has a very useful tool to track all the current parameters of the ISS:

http://isslive.com/displays/adcoDisplay1.html

As of now, the mass reads as **390,377.5 kg.**

---

Update, 22-June-2018:

New link: https://isslive.com/displays/topoDisplay1.html

and a new mass! **417,501.56 kg.**

Answer (score 2):

The historical data can be found in the On-Orbit Assembly, Modeling, and Mass Properties Data Book:

- [On-Orbit Assembly, Modeling, and Mass Properties Data Book volume 1](http://athena.ecs.csus.edu/~grandajj/ME296M/RevAB_Volume%20I%20Signed_updated.pdf), 2008
- [On-Orbit Assembly, Modeling, and Mass Properties Data Book volume 2](http://athena.ecs.csus.edu/~grandajj/ME296M/RevAB_Volume%20II%20Signed_updated.pdf), 2008

I haven't found a more recent edition than 2008.